# Avoiding automatic closing of a DIV

Tags: reactjs

In my react code I have a

```
   <div>
```

that every time its content is deleted it kind of closes. If I place content like just  0  it keeps on. Is there a way, using React styling objects, to prevent that

```
  <div>
```

from disappearing?

Comment: Is your problem that the empty div's dimensions are 0?

Comment: I think this is the problem as I never specify minimum dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when you remove the content, the `<div>` shrinks to 0 height or width.

In that case, if you are using inline styling, try the following - `<div style={{minHeight: 100px, minWidth: 100px}}>`. Obviously you can adjust these values as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Give the `div` a minHeight

```
<div style={{minHeight:20, backgroundColor:'#cafada'}}></div>
```